# How to make POST to Instagram API with Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, instagram

Can I make a call to Instagram API in order to make a comment or like photo, using only JavaScript. I use angular framework with grunt and I don't want to involve any backend. So far I figured out that making GET request is possible using JSONP. What about POST requests? Is it possible?

Comment: POST is not possible. The only way anything other than GET (through jsonp) could work is if the API would support CORS. And it does not: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/instagram-api-developers/pi0XHPJNK8E

Comment: so without help of server there is no possibility to comment media on Instagram, right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using AngularJS and Instagram API together and had some problems with POSTing data to the API with Angular. Here's my experience:

You can do the regular `$http.get` to GET data from Instagram's API! Awesome!

To POST, some methods on the API like `/v1/media/{mediaId}/likes?acess_token...` I used the  `$http.post` and it worked just fine. But to call the method to *follow* or *unfollow* user, it didn't work! It kept saying I missed some parameters (like `action` in this case).

I solved this by using jQuery's ajax to POST. But I didn't want the whole jQuery library on my application, I just wanted the Ajax part of it, so I found this project called [jqAjax](https://github.com/dbennett455/jqAjax). And I POSTed like this:

```
jqAjax.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'+userId+'/relationship?access_token=' + access_token,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {action:'follow'},
                traditional: true,
                success: function (data) 
                {
                   doSomething(data);
                   // or deferred.resolve(data); if you want to use $q.defer() 
                }
             });
```

And it works like a charm! Probably not the best workaround for an Angular application, but I couldn't make `$http.post` work with Instagram API any other way, so....

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the below code, it executes the action well, but I am unable to get the success: to execute with error "Cross-Origin Request Blocked".

In other words, it will post the action, but it won't allow you to read the result for confirmation...painful.

$.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              "method": "POST",

```
          url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' + followID + '/relationship?access_token=' + accessToken + '&callback=callbackFunction',

          data: {action: 'follow'},/*need this to access the relationship*/
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data){
          alert("hello");
```

}
});